Magento 2: How to create dynamic fields with multiple fields in the admin system configuration?
I am currently developing an extension for Magento 2 but am facing an issue when I add an editor in the dynamic field.

Reference: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/admin/create-dynamic-row-configuration/

Which Issue you are facing into this one?

I can't add an editor in the dynamic field.

Share the code into question which you try.
